# How to use cron jobs in Angular 7

Tags: angular, angular7

I am implementing a small application based on Angular 7 and stuck in the area of implementing the cron jobs that will keep calling a back-end service.

And i don't want to rely on intervals or anything similar, because it will go through a cron editor

My question is, what libraries or modules or any approach you would suggest to implement this properly

Comment: Anything wrong with any of the cron javascript libraries out there? (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron)

Comment: I am not sure of this, since i am just explaining about the best suggestion